# Installing Wireless Display, Windows face Unlock via PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Windows 10 added a new Optional Windows Features screen.

[image]

It has different features from the "old" Turn Windows Feaures On/Off screen:

[image]

I know how to turn the features in the second screen on/off using PowerShell using the `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online`, `Enable-`, `Disable-` command. Yet none of the features in the first screen show up in this list.

Which other set of PowerShell/DISM commands can I use to change:

- Uninstall IE11
- Install Wireless Display
- Uninstall Windows Media Player
- Install OpenSSH client

etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these are called Windows Capabilities in tech-speak and packages can be turned on/off using:

```
 Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "XPS.Viewer*" | Remove-WindowsCapability -Online
```

And the same applies to adding a capability:

```
 Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "OpenSSH.Client*" | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

Listing all available capabilities:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online
```